# Issue with paperclip-dropbox, not show images in records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paperclip, dropbox

I have rails web app, I connect it with paperclip-dropbox. Upload works good, but i can't open images on my app. When i try open image i get web address: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/393213417/Koala_medium.jpg  and issue: "It seems you don't belong here! You should probably sign in. Check out our Help Center and forums for help, or head back to home. "

model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "150x150>" },
  :storage => :dropbox,
      :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
      :dropbox_visibility => 'public'

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


  validates_presence_of :topic, content:   "- Dopisz"

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [paperclip-dropbox is producing old-style Dropbox "Public" links](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/dropbox/public_url_generator.rb), which aren't enabled on every account. You can find information about Dropbox Public links here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/16

If it isn't enabled on your account, your resulting link will fail like that, with the 403 error.

Instead, the Dropbox API offers an actual API endpoint for getting links to files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares

These links can be modified for different behaviors as desired, as shown here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201